# OfficeDev PNP : AddClientSitePage not working with a Subsite

Tags: sharepoint, csom

Using the following code in LINQPad, using the latest (3.24.2008) OfficeDev SharePoint PnP Core Library for SharePoint Online

```
void Main()
{
    var baseSite = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com";
    var sharepointSite = "/ussdallas";
    var siteUrl = $"{baseSite}{sharepointSite}";
    var userEmailAddress = "nhodge@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";

    var pageName = "ContosoMarketResearch.aspx";
    
    var authenticationManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

    var context = authenticationManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, "nhodge@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", "contoso!contoso");
    
    var web = context.Web;

    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery(); 

    var subSite = web.GetWeb("redoctober"); // the "sub site" of the "ussdallas" site is "redoctober"

    var subSitePage = subSite.AddClientSidePage(pageName, true);
    
    subSitePage.Save();
        
}
```

(the *true* in `AddClientSidePage()` forces a save to SharePoint)

The **result** is that the ClientSidePage is constructed in `ussdallas` 's Site Pages library rather than the `redoctober` sub-site's Site Pages Library.

From what I can determine the `ClientContext` returned from `web.GetWeb()` is still set to the Parent's (`ussdallas`) `ClientContext` ... and this is why the page is made in the wrong Web.

Looking at the source for `OfficeDev SharePoint PnP Core Library` ... but I cannot work out how to "swap" contexts. Do I make another one? The user is already logged in at this point.

Is there any known solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to swap the contexts by the following way:

```
      context= authenticationManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl + "/sub1", userName, password);
      var subSite = context.Web;
      context.Load(subSite);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      var subSitePage = subSite.AddClientSidePage(pageName, true);
      subSitePage.Save();
```

Comment: OK: the above works. looks like my code will have to re-authenticate

Using

`.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl + "/redoctober");` ... could be interesting to see if it re-popups the browser based login